# How to create/define a sub resource via XML in API-Platform?

Tags: symfony, api-platform.com

I am trying to create a sub resource via XML using Api Platform.

When I define the sub resource via a annotation on the entity, everything works as expected:

Entity/SocialProfile/SocialProfile.php

```php
/**
 * @ApiSubresource()
 * 
 * @ORM\OneToMany(
 *     targetEntity="SoapSyliusSocialPlugin\Entity\Follow\Follow",
 *     mappedBy="follower",
 *     cascade={ "persist", "remove" }
 * )
 */
protected $following;
```

Everything works as expected and I can then access the sub resource via the below path:

`/api/v2/social-profiles/35471/followings`

But when I try define this route/endpoint via .xml like the below:

Resources/config/api_resources/SocialProfile.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" ?>

<resources xmlns="https://api-platform.com/schema/metadata"
           xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
           xsi:schemaLocation="https://api-platform.com/schema/metadata https://api-platform.com/schema/metadata/metadata-2.0.xsd"
>
    <resource class="SoapSyliusSocialPlugin\Entity\SocialProfile\SocialProfile" shortName="SocialProfile">
        <attribute name="validation_groups">sylius</attribute>

        <subresourceOperations>
            <subresourceOperation name="api_social_profiles_followings_get_subresource">
                <attribute name="method">GET</attribute>
            </subresourceOperation>
        </subresourceOperations>

        <property name="following" writable="false" readable="true">
            <subresource resourceClass="SoapSyliusSocialPlugin\Entity\Follow\Follow" />
        </property>


    </resource>
</resources>
```

I am getting a:

> 404 No route found

I have tested my `SocialProfile.xml` file with a `itemOperation` & everything is working as expected.

I have updated my Resources/config/api_resources/SocialProfile.xml to look like the below, but I am still receiving a

> 404 route not found

```
    <?xml version="1.0" ?>

<resources xmlns="https://api-platform.com/schema/metadata"
           xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
           xsi:schemaLocation="https://api-platform.com/schema/metadata https://api-platform.com/schema/metadata/metadata-2.0.xsd"
>
    <resource class="SoapSyliusSocialPlugin\Entity\SocialProfile\SocialProfile" shortName="SocialProfile">
        <attribute name="validation_groups">sylius</attribute>

        <itemOperations></itemOperations>

        <property name="following" writable="false" readable="true">
            <subresource resourceClass="SoapSyliusSocialPlugin\Entity\Follow\Follow"  collection="true"/>
        </property>

    </resource>
</resources>
```

Comment: I have update the Resources/config/api_resources/SocialProfile.xml with the changes suggested, but I am still receiving a 404 route not found.

Comment: How would I add a normalization context to the sub resource operation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The configuration for the entity **holding** the subresource (`SocialProfile`, in this example).

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" ?>

<resources xmlns="https://api-platform.com/schema/metadata"
           xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
           xsi:schemaLocation="https://api-platform.com/schema/metadata https://api-platform.com/schema/metadata/metadata-2.0.xsd"
>
    <resource class="SoapSyliusSocialPlugin\Entity\SocialProfile\SocialProfile" shortName="SocialProfile">
        <attribute name="validation_groups">sylius</attribute>

        <property name="following" writable="false" readable="true">
            <subresource resourceClass="SoapSyliusSocialPlugin\Entity\Follow\Follow" />
        </property>

    </resource>
</resources>
```

To configure things like normalization groups for the subresource, you do it in the other end of the relationship:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" ?>

<resources xmlns="https://api-platform.com/schema/metadata"
           xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
           xsi:schemaLocation="https://api-platform.com/schema/metadata https://api-platform.com/schema/metadata/metadata-2.0.xsd"
>
    <resource class="SoapSyliusSocialPlugin\Entity\Follow\Follow" shortName="Follow">
        
        <subresourceOperations>
            <subresourceOperation name="api_social_profiles_followings_get_subresource">
                <attribute name="method">GET</attribute>
            </subresourceOperation>
        </subresourceOperations>

    </resource>
</resources>
```

Try with this. I have a few setup this way and working. If there is something wrong above should be because something does not match your class/resource names exactly, but you should be able to tweak that to fix it.

Note that in the second version of the configuration in your question you **removed** all `itemOperations`. You should have at least the basic `get` item operation so the library is able to build IRIs.